# What is database instance in cloud foundry?

Tags: database, rdbms, liquibase, cloud-foundry

After running below command,

```
     $ cf create-service-key mysql-db-service MY-KEY
```

There is a file created with name `MY-KEY`(shown below) that has key `name`(database instance) with value `service-instance-db`

```
{
  "hostname": "w-ns27y31.q-g1444.bosh",
  "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:mysql://w-ns27y31.q-g1444.bosh:3306/service_instance_db?user=ccd64a5aa128fffffffffff26d80&password=eddddddd50g&useSSL=false",
  "name": "service_instance_db",
  "password": "el99ffffffffff",
  "port": 3306,
  "uri": "mysql://ccd64a5aa1284dadab01271693d26d80:el9905261y23b50g@w-ns27y31.q-g1444.bosh:3306/service_instance_db?reconnect=true",
  "username": "ccd64ddddddddd271693d26d80"
}
```

If I create a more than one service key file, then `hostname` & `name` remains same in each service key file, but username and password changes

---

In database world, we create **database instance** with syntax: `create DATABASE` statement

And an application runs on that database instance say `instance1`

For another new different application, we create another database  instance say `instance2`

---

1) Is value `service-instance-db` for key `name` a database instance? In service key file `MY-KEY`

2) if yes, then we create a separate  service key file on [mysql-db-service](https://docs.pivotal.io/p-mysql/2-4/) app for each new db application on cloud foundry, but I see same database instance name `service-instance-db` in  service key file. How do I understand this?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is value some-service-db for key name a database instance? In service key file MY-KEY

It honestly depends on the service broker how this is handled. Generally, running `cf create-service` will create an instance of the service and running `cf bind-service` or `cf create-service-key` will create a set of credentials you can use to access the service.

It depends on the broker though as to what exactly happens. Running `cf create-service` can result in anything from a partition in a shared multi-tenant service to a set of dedicated VMs running a cluster of your service.

> 2) if yes, then we create a separate service key file on mysql-db-service app for each new db application on cloud foundry, but I see same database instance name some-service-db in service key file. How do I understand this?

In most cases, the service key is just a new, likely unique, set of credentials for accessing the service instance. You need to look at the docs for your service broker to see exactly how this is handled though.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How multi tenant service relates to having same database instance name for multiple applications?

Comment: Some database are naturally multi-tenant and separate workloads by default, others are not. If a service is not naturally multi-tenant then it will often be deployed where there is one totally separate instance per user. That way there are no noisy neighbor or security problems.

Comment: Added more details in the query